# Wizard architecture in Svelte

Tags: svelte

I'm implementing a multi-step form as a wizard in Svelte, and my implementation so far is awful.

Here's an abstract sketch:

[image: wizard sketch]

I have architected it generally like this:

```
Wizard
  -* FooStepButton (nested inside wizard's progress bar)
    - [button content]
    - [step-specific form content]
```

The problem is, the way I've implemented it, the form fields are a DOM child of the respective progress bar button, and I used `display: fixed` to break out of the absolutely-positioned progress bar. I knew this was a hack, and it works on desktop but not on the iPad, so it's time to not be hacky.

The way I've designed it, I would need something like a `slot` with multiple children, that way each `FooStep` could render the form content in the wizard's content slot. Or, I could do it some other way entirely, so long as the form content and progress bar are siblings.

Something something slots and context?

Comment: Do you mean something like this [https://svelte.dev/examples#svelte-component](https://svelte.dev/examples#svelte-component) ?

Comment: ^ Ooooo that might do it, not sure exactly how but seems like the right direction!

Comment: You could define an array where each element is a component and display the current component (i.e. the current step of the form, kept by the array index). I implemented it this way for a sidebar that shall change the content based on the clicked element (though, I used a dictionary instead of an array)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

- `StepA`, `StepB` etc. are your dialog pages.
- `data` contains the shared data between all pages. Each page has a [prop](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/declaring-props) called `data`.
- `save(data)` is called at the end
- To continue, the user clicks on the [Continue] button.
- The page can optionally send an [event](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-events) "continue", which automatically continues to the next page, without the user clicking on the [Continue] button. Most pages won't need that.

pagedDialog.svelte:

```
<script>
  import { StepA, StepB, StepC, save } from "./steps.svelte"; // your app
  let allSteps = [ StepA, StepB, StepC ];
  let currentStep = StepA;
  let data = {}; // shared data between components

  function cancel() {
    window.close();
  }

  function continueStep() {
    let nextStep = allSteps[allSteps.indexOf(currentStep) + 1];
    if (nextStep) {
      currentStep = nextStep;
    } else { // end
      save(data);
      window.close();
    }
  }
</script>

<h1>Follow these steps to complete the task</h1>

{#each allSteps as step}
  {#if currentStep == step }
    <svelte:component this={step} bind:data on:continue={continueStep}/>
  {/if}
{/each}

<hbox id="buttons">
  <button id="cancel" on:click={cancel}>Cancel</button>
  <button id="continue" on:click={continueStep}>
    {#if currentStep == allSteps[allSteps.length - 1]}
      Done
    {:else}
      Continue
    {/if}
  </button>
</hbox>
```